# map the default id with user defines zid is not letting to insert data

Tags: postgresql, grails

i have a domain class   `Zbusiness`  and I want to insert data into zbusiness table but i don't want to use grails default id to insert data so i used `id generator:'assigned', name:'zid',` as i have replaced grails default primary key id with `zid` column of my `zbusiness`table now i cannot insert the data into database.It is showing `Error initializing the application: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [myshaheen.Zbusiness]:  null
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [myshaheen.Zbusiness]:  null` `ids should be manually inserted before save` what should i do ?is there any way to pass `zid` as `id` to insert data into `zbusiness` table.

I want that default `id field` will be replaced by `zid value` automatically not manually.i will give input to `xshort,xtaxnum ,xadd1 ,xadd2` and zid field will be populated with a specific value being incremented just like `id`
here is my domain class
//Zbusiness.groovy

```
 class Zbusiness implements Serializable{ 
 String xshort
 String xtaxnum
 String xadd1
 String xadd2

static mapping = {
    version false
    id generator:'assigned', name:'zid'
    xtaxnum  length: 100
    xshort length: 100
    xadd1 length: 100
    xadd2 length: 100
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `zid` before you save the object?

Comment: no i didnt try it..i have no clear idea how to use it..i used setter getter method in netbeans using jsp servlet but not in grails..how is it done

Comment: How are you creating the `Zbusiness` object currently?

Comment: Zbusiness object is being created when I run the application.but ` Error initializing the application: **Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [myshaheen.Zbusiness]:  null
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [myshaheen.Zbusiness]:  null`** this error is showing.   But when I comment these two lines    **version false
        id generator:'assigned', name:'zid'** then grails home page show and i can insert data by clicking the ZbusinessController

Answer (score 0):

Your ID mapping performs two functions:

1. `generator:'assigned'` - Indicates that you are going to set the ID's manually.
2. `name:'zid'` - Changes the ID property from `id` to `zid`.

Notice that the `name` attribute changes the ID *property* not the *column*. You said:

*...as i have replaced grails default primary key id with zid column of my zbusinesstable...*

But that's not what happened. Instead you partially replaced the Grails default ID property `id` with `zid`. I say *partially* because you instructed Grails to use a property (`zid`) which does not exist in your domain class.

## What now?

Since the `zbusiness` table has a primary key column named `zid`, to use this column as the domain class's ID you'll need to use the *column* attribute:

```
id generator:'assigned', column:'zid'
```

With the mapping shown above in place, you can create an instance of `Zbusiness` like this:

```
def instance = new Zbusiness(id: 123, xshort: 'a', xtaxnum: 'b', xadd1: 'c', xadd2: 'd').save()
```

In the example above, I set the *id* manually prior to `save()`'ing the instance, using the property named *id*.

Comment: where should I create the def instance?inside the controller or  inside the domain class and i only want to set id manually other fields will be populated by user input

Comment: it's not working I wrote **def instance = new Zbusiness(id: 123).save()** in controller.I did not write other 4 variables because they will be saved using grails crud functionality i need to save id value manually  such as 65000,65001 etc.Last used **id generator:'sequence', column:'zid', type:'long'** now it is saving id value but 1,2,3 not my assigned value

Comment: Firstly, to save an instance it must pass validation. In your example domain class the other four properties are not nullable, so if you don't assign then values prior to saving the save will fail. Second, your assigned id is being rejected because the generator is set to sequence

Comment: It needs to be set to assigned.

Comment: This is the place where i have stuck.I have set id generator as assigned but how do i assign any value should i give default value:650000? such as *  id generator: 'assigned', column: 'zid', type: 'long',  default value:650000 ** because i have set * * id generator: 'assigned' * but it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95399/discussion-between-emmanuel-rosa-and-sarah5).